# WebGL: Count the number of rendered vertices

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl

Using the WebGL API, is there a way to count the number of vertices rendered within a given canvas? I've seen some tools that attempt to accomplish this task but some are giving strange results (e.g. Three.js' `renderer.info.render` is reporting my scene has 10,134.3 triangles).

Any help with using the raw WebGL API to count the number of rendered vertices (and, ideally, points and lines) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebGL can't do this for you but you could can add your own augmentation.

The most obvious way is just to track your own usage. Instead of calling `gl.drawXXX` call `functionThatTracksDrawingCountsXXX` and track the values yourself.

You can also augment the WebGL context itself. Example

```js
// copy this part into a file like `augmented-webgl.js`
// and include it in your page

(function() {
  // NOTE: since WebGL constants are um, constant
  // we could statically init this.
  let primMap;

  function addCount(ctx, type, count) {
    const ctxInfo = ctx.info;
    const primInfo = primMap[type];
    ctxInfo.vertCount += count;
    ctxInfo.primCount[primInfo.ndx] += primInfo.fn(count);
  } 
 
  WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.drawArrays = (function(oldFn) {
    return function(type, offset, count) {
      addCount(this, type, count);
      oldFn.call(this, type, offset, count);
    };
  }(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.drawArrays));
  
  WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.drawElements = (function(oldFn) {
    return function(type, count, indexType, offset) {
      addCount(this, type, count);
      oldFn.call(this, type, count, indexType, offset);
    };
  }(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.drawElements));
  
  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = (function(oldFn) {
    return function(type, ...args) {
      const ctx = oldFn.call(this, type, args);
      if (ctx && type === "webgl") {
        if (!primMap) {
          primMap = {};
          primMap[ctx.POINTS] = { ndx: 0, fn: count => count, };
          primMap[ctx.LINE_LOOP] = { ndx: 1, fn: count => count, };
          primMap[ctx.LINE_STRIP]= { ndx: 1, fn: count => count - 1, };
          primMap[ctx.LINES] = { ndx: 1, fn: count => count / 2 | 0, };
          primMap[ctx.TRIANGLE_STRIP] = { ndx: 2, fn: count => count - 2, };
          primMap[ctx.TRIANGLE_FAN] = { ndx: 2, fn: count => count - 2, };
          primMap[ctx.TRIANGLES] = { ndx: 2, fn: count => count / 3 | 0, }; 
        };
        ctx.info = {
          vertCount: 0,
          primCount: [0, 0, 0],
        };
      }
      return ctx;
    }
  }(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext));
}());

// ---- cut above ----

const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: $('canvas')});

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const items = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
  let item;
  switch(rand(0, 3) | 0) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
     const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: rand(0xFFFFFF) | 0,
        wireframe: rand(0, 3) > 2,
      });
      item = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      break;
    case 2:
      const pmat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        color: rand(0xFFFFFF) | 0,
      });
      item = new THREE.Points(geometry, pmat);
      break;
    default:
      throw "oops";
  }
  item.position.x = rand(-10, 10);
  item.position.y = rand(-10, 10);
  item.position.z = rand(  0, -50);
  scene.add(item);
  items.push(item);
}

camera.position.z = 5;

const countElem = $('#count');

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  resize();

  // animate the items
  items.forEach((items, ndx) => {
    items.rotation.x = time * 1.2 + ndx * 0.01;
    items.rotation.y = time * 1.1;
  });
  
  // turn on/off a random items
  items[rand(items.length) | 0].visible = Math.random() > .5;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
  // get the current counts
  const info = renderer.context.info;
  countElem.textContent = `    VERTS: ${info.vertCount}
   POINTS: ${info.primCount[0]}
    LINES: ${info.primCount[1]}
TRIANGLES: ${info.primCount[2]}`;
  
  // zero out the count
  renderer.context.info.vertCount = 0;
  renderer.context.info.primCount = [0, 0, 0];
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function rand(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function resize() {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspectRatio = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}
```

```css
body { border: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
#ui { position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 1em; background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); color: white; padding: .5em; width: 10em; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="ui">
  <pre id="count"></pre>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
```

Of course you might want to add support for drawArraysInstanced etc... and support for WebGL2.

Comment: Are vertices a valid thing to measure at all, as per the other answer? (triangles, points, lines)

Answer (score 2):

We removed the amount of processed vertices from `renderer.info.render` since the important measurement is the amount or rendered primitives (so triangles, points, lines). Please read https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/13404 and the related issues/PRs for more information. If you still want to know how many vertices were processed, you need to count manually. WebGL can't do this for you.